# Error i cant figure out

Tags: java

OK so im not sure why this program isn't working I was working on this project in school and its unfinished but now whenever i try to run it i get the error message

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problem: at Means34.main(Means34.java:96)

even if i delete lines of code so there is no line 96 i still get this message. Can anyone give me any idea as to why this is happening?

```
import java.awt.*;
import BreezyGUI.*;

public class Means34 extends GBFrame{
    public Means34(){
        setTitle("Draw + means");
        red.setBackground(Color.red);
        green.setBackground(Color.green);
        pink.setBackground(Color.pink);
        blue.setBackground(Color.blue);
        magenta.setBackground(Color.magenta);
        cyan.setBackground(Color.cyan);
    }
    static Frame frm;
    Label firstNumLabel = addLabel ("Input: First Num",1,1,1,1);
    DoubleField firstNumField= addDoubleField (0,1,2,1,1);
    Label secondNumLabel = addLabel ("Input: Second Num",2,1,1,1);
    DoubleField secondNumField = addDoubleField (0,2,2,1,1);
    Label arithmeticLabel = addLabel ("Output: Arithmetic",3,1,1,1);
    DoubleField arithmeticField= addDoubleField (0,3,2,1,1);
    Label harmonicLabel = addLabel ("Output: Harmonic",4,1,1,1);
    DoubleField harmonicField= addDoubleField (0,4,2,1,1);
    Label geometricLabel = addLabel ("Output: Geometric",5,1,1,1);
    DoubleField geometricField= addDoubleField (0,5,2,1,1);
    Button convertButton= addButton ("Find Means",6,1,1,1);
    Button clearButton= addButton ("Clear",6,2,1,1);
    Label coll1Label = addLabel ("Color 1",7,1,1,1);
    Label coll2Label = addLabel ("Color 2",7,2,1,1);
    Label col1Label = addLabel ("               ",8,1,1,1);
    Label col2Label = addLabel ("               ",8,2,1,1);
    Label meancoll=addLabel ("Mean Color",7,3,1,1);
    Label meancol=addLabel ("               ",8,3,1,1);
    Button red = addButton ("               ",1,3,1,1);
    Button green = addButton ("               ",2,3,1,1);
    Button pink = addButton ("               ",3,3,1,1);
    Button blue = addButton ("               ",4,3,1,1);
    Button magenta = addButton ("              ",5,3,1,1);
    Button cyan = addButton ("               ",6,3,1,1);
    Checkbox colorone= addCheckbox("Choose first color",4,4,1,1);
    Checkbox colortwo= addCheckbox("Choose second color",5,4,1,1);



    double first;
    double second;
    double arithmetic;
    double harmonic;
    double geometric;
    Color meancolor;



    public  void colorer(Checkbox check, Button buttonObj, Button butt, Label labal, Color coler){
        if (check.getState()){
            if (buttonObj==butt){
                labal.setBackground(coler);
            }
        }
    }

    public void buttonClicked (Button buttonObj) {
        colorer(colorone, buttonObj,cyan,col1Label,Color.cyan);
        colorer(colorone, buttonObj,red,col1Label,Color.red);
        colorer(colorone, buttonObj,green,col1Label,Color.green);
        colorer(colorone, buttonObj,pink,col1Label,Color.pink);
        colorer(colorone, buttonObj,blue,col1Label,Color.blue);
        colorer(colorone, buttonObj,magenta,col1Label,Color.magenta);
        colorer(colortwo, buttonObj,cyan,col2Label,Color.cyan);
        colorer(colortwo, buttonObj,red,col2Label,Color.red);
        colorer(colortwo, buttonObj,green,col2Label,Color.green);
        colorer(colortwo, buttonObj,pink,col2Label,Color.pink);
        colorer(colortwo, buttonObj,blue,col2Label,Color.blue);
        colorer(colortwo, buttonObj,magenta,col2Label,Color.magenta);
        if (buttonObj==convertButton){
            first=firstNumField.getNumber();
            second=secondNumField.getNumber();
            arithmetic= (first + second)/2 ;
            harmonic= ((1/first) + (1/second))/2;
            geometric= Math.sqrt((first*second)) ;
            arithmeticField.setNumber(arithmetic);
            harmonicField.setNumber(harmonic);
            geometricField.setNumber(geometric);
            frm.revalidate();
        }
    }

    public void mouseDragged(int x, int y){
        Graphics l= getGraphics();
        l.setColor(Color.green);
        l.fillOval((x -50),(y - 50),10,10);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        frm= new Means34();
        frm.setSize (300,300);
        frm.setVisible (True);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line is line 96?

Comment: Deleting lines does not change nothing unless you recompile it. Recompile your code and tell us which line (mark it in your code) is giving the issue. Also notice the compilation messages, because they will inform you better of the real problem.

Comment: Which is line 96? Is it this one `frm.setVisible (false);` ? Given GBFrame extends Frame, there is no error on that line.

Comment: Recompile your code and see if there is any improvement?

Comment: Yea that is the line and it was set to true i changed to false messing around to see if i could change error at all

Comment: You should check the compilation errors before trying to run the program. It would give you a more informative message.

Comment: I have recompiled even made a new program with different name all same code and got the same error

Comment: So when you deleted lines of code so that there was no line 96 and still got the same error, how many lines were there in the file in total? Is this still the case: i.e you have 90 lines (for example) in the program and still get the error message saying there's an error on line 96?

Comment: In the code im displaying here there are 98 lines total and yep even when i delete empty space lines so that there are less than 96 i still get that error

Comment: It compiles and runs fine for me, except that I had to change the line frm.setVisible (True); to frm.setVisible (true);

Comment: Yea that was just me messing around after i got the error trying to change it lol but it is working for me now for some reason. I made absolutely zero changes but this time when i tried to run it it worked.

Comment: You did make changes (messing around): you told us about them! I understand what you're saying though. You're saying you orginally had frm.setVisible (true); or frm.setVisible (false); when it gave the error. If that's the case, I'm as mystified as you

Answer (score 1):

It compiles and runs fine for me, except that I had to change the line

```
frm.setVisible (True);
```

to

```
frm.setVisible (true);
```